# Remove header of VuetifyJS v-tabs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tabs, vuetify.js

I need the functionality of this [VuetifyJS v-tabs *NEXT TAB*](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs#usage--1) component but without the navigation header. How to remove it?

[Here is a CodePen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wxzRpY?&editors=101)

```
<v-tabs
  v-model="active"
  color="cyan"
  dark
  slider-color="yellow"
>
  <v-tab
    v-for="n in 3"
    :key="n"
    ripple
  >
    Item {{ n }}

  </v-tab>
  <v-tab-item
    v-for="n in 3"
    :key="n"
  >
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>{{ text }}</v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs>

<div class="text-xs-center mt-3">
  <v-btn @click="next">next tab</v-btn>
</div>
```

Comment: Wait what? You mean `.v-tabs__bar {display: none}`?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I was thinking in the wrong direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.v-tabs__bar {display: none}`

Tho you might want to add a custom selector.

Or think about different approach for your functionality (use-case) because the purpose of tabs  is to have... well... tabs.